# Должен ли zram резервировать память в RAM?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Я настроил zram на своем компе.
У меня на компе 14GB физической RAM.

Я настроил zram, вот скрипт настройки:

```
#!/bin/bash
modprobe zram num_devices=4
echo '5500M' > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
echo '5500M' > /sys/block/zram1/disksize
echo '5500M' > /sys/block/zram2/disksize
echo '5500M' > /sys/block/zram3/disksize
mkswap /dev/zram0
swapon /dev/zram0 -p 10
mkswap /dev/zram1
swapon /dev/zram1 -p 10
mkswap /dev/zram2
swapon /dev/zram2 -p 10
mkswap /dev/zram3
swapon /dev/zram3 -p 10
```

В итоге у меня появилось 21GB swap памяти:
[image: htop]

Но я ожидал, что объем доступной RAM должен уменьшиться. Но этого не произошло.

1. Почему zram не зарезервировал часть RAM для своих виртуальных девайсов?
2. Почему я смог создать zram на 21GB, когда у меня физической RAM 14GB?
3. Как понять, что zram работает? Как увидеть, что он зарезервировал память для swap?

Comment: Чтобы память израсходовалась ее надо заполнить рандомными данными. А пустое оно все в 0 сжимается.

Comment: @user7860670 вопрос был другой

Comment: Мой первый комментарий отвечает сразу на все 3 вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Пустой файл подкачки очень хорошо сжимается, так как не содержит данных. Когда в подкачку уйдут какие-то данные, то эти данные сожмутся и займут место в оперативной памяти. В какойто момент zram будет нехватать памяти и он будет вытеснять другие приложения в свап, от этого толстеть, опять непомещаться и снова кушатьчужую память пока не наступит OOM и кто-то умрет.